How to import fenics in Jupyter notebook
I am using Jupyter Notebook to try and solve Poisson's equation using FeniCS. I already appended the folder path to sys, already checked if the module is in the folder but it still says that there is "No module named fenics" when I try to import it like this:
from fenics import *

When I try pip installing it again it says it is already installed. Also when I use:
help('modules')

FeniCS does not appear at all.
Has someone encountered a problem like this?
I can use numpy, scipy, etc. which are all in the same libraries.
I also already checked my current python version and it is 3.8, the same where I pip installed FeniCS.
Thank you in advance.

Try the suggestion here: https://fem-on-colab.github.io/packages.html or https://fenics.readthedocs.io/projects/containers/en/latest/jupyter.html

In general, that type of import is not advised, see here and elsewhere. Also see here. I used the magic install command, %conda install -c conda-forge fenics, in a fresh notebook cell in an environment where I was using the Anaconda/conda package manaager, based on link from that thread. After that completed and I restarted kernel, and in next cell ran ...

 import fenics, and it worked. Jupyter kernels run in environments where it has to see things. Just anywhere on your system won't usually cut it.
